# Fit a polynomial/curve to an NIntegrate result

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, fitting, polynomials

I want to `NIntegrate` a function which also contains some parameter. In the end, I would like to plot the result as a function of one of these parameters. The thing is I would like to scatter plot the result and then fit a curve through them. I already know how to plot a line but then I don't know how to fit a polynomial to the result.

More specifically, suppose we have a function

```
f[p_]:= NIntegrate[p*Exp[-x],{x,0,Infinity}];
```

Now I could plot this the usual way for a range, say p=0..1 of the parameter p via  `Plot[f[p],{p,0,1}]` But in this way I would get a curve without any info on its (approximate) analytical shape. What I want is to know the approximate analytical shape of the plot, i.e. if it's linear or quadratic and so on. 
So I was thinking of scatter-plotting (like in Excel) and then fitting a curve to read of the approximate shape of the curve.

Is this possible in a simple way?

Comment: ...and you've looked at `FindFit[]`?

Comment: @J.M.isback. Yes, but I have a hard time seeing how to apply it to my case (maybe it's trivial and I'm just tired?)

Comment: I think that minimum due diligence does include searching the documentation for the keywords of your question before posting.

Comment: ...or searching this site using those tags.

Comment: I've searched here and the Mathematica page. My problem was not knowing how to save the "scatter-data". I guess I should use `Table[]´ for that?

Comment: Could you post a more complicated example? For the example you posted,  you can simply pull `p` out of the integral to get `f[p] == p`.

Comment: Yes it's a trivial example.

Comment: I'm more old-fashioned and would suggest doing the "scatter plot" first (even though the only "errors" are about machine precision and lack-of-fit rather than the usual random and independent errors) and then thinking about what kind of curve might be appropriate.  After that FindFit with a candidate functional form would be appropriate.  If you want no thinking at all, then the experimental `FindFormula` might be helpful.

Comment: Man wtf is wrong with you guys? This site will end up a graveyard if you continue like this bitching about someone that asks questions.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed from your username that a bit of sarcasm would be tolerated.  Maybe this might be a topic for Mathematica Meta in that "how" to do things don't always come with additional advice about potential consequences.  I would think that besides the great grammatical help given in this forum the wide range of experience available from using such techniques is an even better service.

Comment: @JimBaldwin That comment was not directed at you but at those above your comment (or perhaps you're sarcastic again? ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the table with the data

```
data = Table[
  {
   p,
   NIntegrate[p*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
   }
  , {p, 0, 1, 1/10}
  ]

    (* {{0, 0.}, {1/10, 0.1}, {1/5, 0.2}, {3/10, 0.3}, {2/5, 
  0.4}, {1/2, 0.5}, {3/5, 0.6}, {7/10, 0.7}, {4/5, 0.8}, {9/10, 
  0.9}, {1, 1.}} *)
```

Using [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html)

```
Fit[
 data
 , {1, x, x^2}
 , x]
(* -4.64784*10^-16 + 1. x - 5.58029*10^-16 x^2 *)
```

[`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the points and the `Fit`

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data]
 , Plot[
  Evaluate@Fit[
    data
    , {1, x, x^2}
    , x], {x, 0, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)

```
ClearAll[c,x]
FindFit[
 data
 , FromDigits[Reverse@Array[c, 4], x]
 , Array[c, 4]
 , x]
(* {c[1] -> -2.04192*10^-16, c[2] -> 1., 
 c[3] -> 2.79015*10^-15, c[4] -> -2.05223*10^-15} *)
```

Notice that `FromDigits[Reverse@Array[c, 4], x]` creates the Polynomial degree 4

```
FromDigits[Reverse@Array[c, 4], x]
(* c[1] + x c[2] + x^2 (c[3] + x c[4]) *)
```

and `Array[c, 4]` the list of coefficients `{c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}`

Comment: This makes sense, thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: How did you obtain this info: (* -4.64784*10^-16 + 1. x - 5.58029*10^-16 x^2 *) ?

Comment: The commented code `(*  *)` is the output of the function before it.

Comment: Thanks this was awesome. Step by step and clear, perfect.

Answer (score 5):

With version 10.2 you can use the EXPERIMENTAL function [`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
Clear[f]
```

Note that the definition of a function defined using a numerical technique (e.g., [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) should be restricted to numeric arguments.

```
f[p_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[p*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]

data = Table[{p, f[p]}, {p, .1, 1, .1}];

FindFormula[data, p]

(*  1. p  *)
```

Using exact numbers

```
dataR = data // Rationalize[#, 10^-10] &;

FindFormula[dataR, p]

(*  p  *)
```

Comment: I upvoted partly because of your emphasis on the word "experimental". :)